Photon shot in opposite direction of spaceship, what is its relative velocity?
Okay, lets say you have frame S which is a spaceship who is travelling with speed v = c/3 relative to S' which is some planet Y. In the spaceship two photons are shot in opposite direction, to the right and the left. What would the velocity of both photons be in the S' frame. I think the one to the right, which let's say is positive would have +c photon, so relatively its travelling with 2c/3. But how fast does the other go, as it can't go faster than the light speed. I'm really stuck with this so any help is much appreciated!!

See postulate 2 of SR: “The speed of light in vacuum is the same for all observers, regardless of the motion of light source or observer.” Photons in vacuum move at speed $c$.

Does this answer your question? Speed of light $> c$?

A photon in a vacuum is always traveling with $v=c$. The relative speed of the two photons to each other is $2c$, in both the system of the spaceship and the planet.
On the planet, the photon going in forward direction has relative speed to the spaceship of $2/3c$, and the backwards travelling photon $4/3c$.
In the spaceship, the forwards backwards moving photon both have a relative speed of $c$, w.r.t. to the ship.

The relative speed of the two photons isn't $2c$ in a system boosted in the direction perpendicular to the spaceship, if we define "relative speed" to be the norm of the difference of their three-velocities!  One reason why "relative speed of two photons" isn't  a particularly useful notion...

@RokasVeitas I'll edit

I'd appreciate a comment why some people think this answer is wrong or not helpful.

I didn't downvote, though the statement the relative speed of the two photons to each other is 2c is not coherent. It seems to suggest that a photon has a "rest frame" so that "in the frame of one photon it observes the other moving at 2c".

@josephh But that's not what I said. I'm well aware that a photon doesn't have a rest frame. I said in the two systems, the planet and the spaceship. But I'll clarify once more.

@infinitezero hi. It is what you said. It's directly quoted from your answer above. Thx

@joseph so if you shoot two photons in the opposite direction, what is the distance between them after 1 year?

That was not the point of contention. Thx

The velocity of photons in all reference frames is c.  This is true for the ship, the planet, and even the photons themselves, if there was a way for a photon to measure the speed of another photon.  This is fundamental to special relativity.  The space contraction and time dilation effects balance out to hold this to be true.

@josephh Than what are you contending? The relative speed can exceed c, because it's not a frame transformation. If your answer to my earlier question is "2 lightyears", than clearly, the relative speed must be "2c". If you have a different answer, please explain. I'd like to learn.

@Michael no one is saying otherwise. This is precisely what I'm saying in my last sentence.
